# Remove commas from end of line in text file with VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I have written a VBA code to output comma seperated data elements to a text file that will then be imported into a seperated application.  However, I am stuck how to remove the end of line commas generated in the text file.
The following is an example of my data:

```
Scenario,Capital,AFE
Capital Array,Drilling Capex 80/20,Replace,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

Capital Array,Facilities Tangible,Replace,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,250,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

Capital Array,Recompletion 80/20,Replace,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be not to add the trailing comma in the first place. To do that, you need to modify the code you have not shown to us.

Alternatively, if the CSV creation code is a black box that you do not want to touch, you can manually remove the last character in a string:

```
myString = "a,b,c,d,"

If Right(myString, 1) = "," Then
    myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
End If

' myString is now "a,b,c,d"
```

Comment: We posted at exactly the same second, I think... but you have better formatting, so I'll upvote yours. Good fast work. ;-)

Comment: @PaluMacil: You were a few seconds faster, in fact, so +1 to you as well. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your string calculated like above, use this to remove the last character: `myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)` where myString is th name of your string. If you don't know if the last char will be a comma every time, first use an if statement checking that `Right(1,myString)` is a comma.